# Connection with PDO using Bind Value not working

Tags: php

I have the following connection which was working fine, but I want to include userID column from the table in a new variable:

```
public function userLogin() 
{
    $success = false;
    try {
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "UserID", $this->userID, PDO::PARAM_STR );

        $stmt->execute();

        $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if( $valid ) {
            $success = true;
        }

        $con = null;
        return $success;
```

when I added my new line `$stmt->bindValue( "UserID", $this->userID, PDO::PARAM_STR );`

it says error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

where might be the problem ?

Comment: u bind 3 values but only use two..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding 3 Values but does use 2values only

on

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
```

if you gonna use ID add it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid= :UserID AND username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
```

*note:bind variables should always exist on your query if not better get rid of it.*

Comment: the username and password are used for the login verification, I want in the SESSION to be sessionized also the userID from the table in another variable, thats why I am not including it in the WHERE Clause

Comment: @JohnSiniger You can just get the userid in fetch area then process your session

Comment: Dont but it unless your gonna used it on your statements else better store is on a default variable for further used.